# Angular ui bootstrap modal call close function when closing from overlay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can i run the same function when the user is closing the modal from the overlay?

For example now i have close button with this function:

```
  close() {
    this.$modalInstance.close();
    this.AlertService.reset();   
  }
```

But when the user close the modal from the overlay this function does not run.

Comment: You can do it in the second parameter to the `modalInstance.result`, i.e., `modalInstance.result.then(function() { ... }, function() { this.AlertService.reset(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [angular bootstrap documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

$modal.open returns a modal instance, with one parameter being 'result'. This is a promise triggered when the modal is dismissed.

```
var $modalInstance =  $modal.open({ ... });

$modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Also, note the modal.closing event which is broadcast before closing, and can be used to prevent closing with 'event.preventDefault'.